# HP LaserJet 5000 driver installation on Windows 10

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, printer

I am having trouble installing an HP LaserJet 5000N printer on my Windows 10 machine.  The printer is currently hooked up to my home network.  A Windows XP machine connects to it via IP address and has the correct driver, so this works.

The Windows 10 machine is set to print also via the IP address, and it sees the printer.  However when I go to choose a driver, the model is not available.  I did install a LaserJet 5100 driver, which I thought might work.  Unfortunately, when I go to print a page, all the characters come out as black text blocks.  This shows, at least, that the computer and printer are communicating with each other.

I have also tried to press the "Windows Update" button on the "Install the printer driver" dialog, but this doesn't show the correct model either.

Can anyone help me find the correct driver, or provide another work around?

If not, is it possible to print via the XP machine from the Windows 10 machine?  They are both hooked up to the same wireless router.

Comment: You might try the pcl5 5000 driver at https://printerdriverseries.com/hp-laserjet-5000-driver-printer-series/, the 5025 or 5035 drivers at https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04675396 or the PostScript driver for 5000 at https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-designjet-5000-printer-series/25300

Comment: Did you try "Microsoft PCL6 Class Driver"?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by trying a [generic PCL6 driver for Windows 10 (64-bit)](https://support.hp.com/ph-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-universal-print-driver-series-for-windows/503548/model/3271552) from HP.

Falling back on generic drivers often works when you can't find specific ones for discontinued models.

Comment: Yes, I did try this as well.  After trying to select the universal driver for this printer, Windows said it was not able to install it, and the driver defaulted back to the original.